# Using keyword argument 'bottom' in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe containing 2 categorical columns and 2 value columns. I want to be able to use the 'bottom' keyword argument when using seaborn's barplot function, but I get a ValueError and ConversionError because it doesn't process "Min Value" the same as the x, y, and hue arguments.

The desired output for this would be a grouped barplot showing a floating bar with the minimum and maximum values for the specified grouping.

Shown below is an example of the non-working code and what my desired output is.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Category 1": ["A","A","A","B","B","B"],
                   "Category 2": ["Bad","Good","Good","Bad","Good","Good"],
                   "Min Value": [2,5,3,4,1,0],
                   "Max Value": [10,5,8,5,11,4]})

sns.barplot(x = "Category 1", y = "Max Value", hue="Category 2", data = df,
            estimator = max,
            ci = 0,
            bottom = "Min Value")
```

Desired Output
[image]

**Update** Modification on the accepted solution to make it more concise.

```
# Group by the categories
df = df.groupby(["Category 1", "Category 2"])
# Columnwise aggregation
df = df.agg({"Min Value": min,"Max Value": max})
# Plot
sns.boxplot(data=df.T)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would be interpreted as bottom = 0 and modify all of the bars to have a  lower value of 0.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, you might want to try the following (please note that this will not result in the exact same graph you posted as the desired output, but I hope it may be of help anyway) :

```
# Construct the DataFrame with MultiIndex:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Min Value": [2,5,3,4,1,0],
                             "Max Value": [10,5,8,5,11,4]})
index_arr = [["A","A","A","B","B","B"],
             ["Bad","Good","Good","Bad","Good","Good"]]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index_arr, 
                                     names=["Category 1", "Category 2"])

# Use groupby to find min and max for each category
df_max = df.groupby(by=['Category 1', 'Category 2']).max()
df_min = df.groupby(by=['Category 1', 'Category 2']).min()

# Set the min values for the first column
df_max.iloc[:,0] = df_min.iloc[:,0]

# Plot the Boxplot (seems more appropriate then barplot)
sns.boxplot(data=df_max.T)
```

Comment: This works thank you! I've modified it to shorted the amount of lines as well as saving a bit of space/time. Edited in the question.